# Cypress Screenshot gives error of typeerror cannot read properties of undefined (reading replaceall)

Tags: cypress, screenshot, replaceall

I am using Cypress on Amazon workspace using Windows Server 2019 Datacentre as OS.
I am trying to take screenshots of a web page and every time getting a same error on my windows that:
Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'replaceAll')
at Object.toPosix (https://www.iciciprulife.com/__cypress/runner/cypress_runner.js:159314:56)
and
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'getBoundingClientRect')
at getViewPercentage (:8:39)

Although my screenshots are getting saved in the screenshot folder but it fails the script execution after taking screenshot.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2wOkJ.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jeuuZ.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zQj3L.png)

Test code to reproduce

```js
describe("example to-do app", () =\> {

    it("Signature Testing", () =\> {
    cy.viewport(1336, 720)

cy.visit("https://www.iciciprulife.com/ulip-plans/unit-linked-insurance-plans/icici-pru-signature-ulip-     calculator.html")
    cy.wait(10000)
    cy.screenshot()
    cy.on("uncaught:exception", (err, runnable) =\> {
    console.log(err)
    return false
    })
    })
    })
```

Cypress Version
12.8.1

Node version
16.14.0

Operating System
Windows Server 2019 datacenter

Desired behavior
I just want to save my screenshots normally without getting any errors and the script should execute succcessfullyafter taking and saving the screenshots.

https://github.com/cypress-io/cypress/issues/26142